# How can I perform a segue from single view controller to split view controller? Swift

Tags: swift, segue, uisplitviewcontroller

I want user to login before going to split view controller. I tried to create a push segue then call the performSegueWithIdentifier. An error comes out. It says "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'fromLoginToTask'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'"

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to utilize UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate [UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate_protocol/index.html)

It's a bit more work to implement, but it should do the proper changing of root view controllers which I think is the issue when trying to use a segue how you describe.

Comment: I fixed it by creating a navigation controller and using a container to contain the split view. Then, it works perfect. Thanks anyway. Please update your answer or keep it as is. I will give you a tick no matter what:)